# Iterating in a matrix Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm having some issue iterating a matrix.
I have this Dataframe:

[Composed of 2 columns and k rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj4bv.png)

[And this Dataframe composed of i rows and j columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U0GC.png)

I would like for each Ex-date to substract the Div in the second Dataframe.
For example, in row 0 of the first Dataframe I have an ex-date equals to 0.04 and a div equals to 1.33 and I want for the second Dataframe where ex-date is almost equal to 0.04 to substract 1.33 for every column (not the first one of course).

Hope this make sense,

Thanks a lot

And this one:

Comment: You shouldn't post photos of your dataframes, you should write them inside the post text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.